# find the smallest positive integer k so that $11 | a_k$ and $11 | (b_k-1)$ for specific sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction, contest-math, recurrence-relations

> Let $a_0 =11, b_0 = 1, a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1} b_n^{2019}, b_{n+1} = b_n b_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 1$. Find the smallest integer $k$ so that $11 | a_k$ and $11 | (b_k-1)$ whenever $a_n$ and $b_n$ are defined as above and satisfy $a_1,b_1 > 0, 11 \nmid b_1.$

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of pairs of sequences $((a_n),(b_n))$ defined as in the problem statement and such that $a_1,b_1, 11\nmid b_1$. Consider a pair $((a_n),(b_n))$ in $\mathcal{S}$. Since there are some $11$'s involved, it might be useful to work modulo 11. We have $b_n^{2019}\equiv b_n^9\mod 11$ (by induction each term $b_n$ is not divisible by $11$). Note that modulo any given prime number p, for any positive integer $k$ coprime to $p-1, \{1, 2^k, \cdots, (p-1)^k\} = \{1,2,\cdots, p-1\}.$ Indeed suppose $i^k \equiv j^k \mod p$ for some $0 < i  < j$. Let  $g $ be a primitive root modulo p. Write $i=g^a, j = g^b$ for some $1\leq a,b \leq p-1.$ Then $(ij^{-1})^k \equiv 1\mod p\Rightarrow (g^{a-b})^k\equiv 1\mod p,$ which implies that $p-1$ must divide $-k(a-b).$ But by assumption $k$ is coprime to $p-1$ so $p-1$ divides $a-b$. Since $0 < |a-b| < p-1,$ we get the desired contradiction. Note that we actually need $k$ to be coprime to $p-1$. For instance, consider $p=5$ and $k=2$. Then $\{1, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2\} \neq \{1,2,3,4\}$ (here the equality of sets is considered modulo 5).  Hence by the above claim, we may be able to simplify the sequence $(b_n)$. Let $b_1 = c$. Then one has that $b_n = c^{f_n}$ where $f_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number by induction. Note that one may assume $a_1 = 1$. From this I think one can derive a formula for $a_n$ (at least modulo 11) by induction.

Comment: Do you mean the smallest $k>0?$ Because it is true for $k=0.$

Comment: $b_n = b_1^{F_n}$ where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers starting $F_0=0, F_1=1.$

Comment: So you need $F_n$ divisible by $10$ to have $11\mid b_n-1.$

Answer (score 1):

The smallest such $k$ is $30$

---

As the asker recommended, we will work modulo 11.

Let $\%$ be the remainder operator.
Let $a_0 =0, b_0 = 1$, $a_{n+1} = (a_n + a_{n-1} b_n^9)\%11$, $b_{n+1} = (b_n b_{n-1})\%11$ for $n\ge 1$. The problem is to find the smallest  positive integer $k$ so that $a_k=0$ and and $b_k=1$ whenever $a_n$ and $b_n$ are defined as above and satisfy $b_1\not=0$.

##### Such $k$ cannot be smaller than $30$.

Consider $a_1=1$.

- Let $b_1=1$.
  $a_i$'s are $0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 10, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 10, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 10, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5,\cdots$.
  $a_n=0$ when $n=0,10, 20, 30, \cdots$, which means such $k$ must be either  $10$ or $20$ if it is $<30$.
- Let $b_1=2$.
  $a_i$'s are $0, 1, 1, 7, 10, 4, 5, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 6, 10, 8, 0, 8, 8, 6, 1, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5, 4, 10, 5, 1, 9, 0, 9, 9, 5, 8, 4,\cdots$.
  $a_n=0$ when $n=0, 15, 30, \cdots$, which means such $k$ must be $15$ if it is $<30$.

##### Such $k$ can be 30

By induction, we see that $b_n=b_1^{F_n}$, where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers starting with $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$.
Computing Fibonacci sequence by modulo $10$, we find that $F_{30}\equiv_{10}0$.
$$b_{30}\equiv_{11} b_1^{F_{30}}\equiv_{11} b_1^{0}=1,$$
where the middle equality uses Fermat's little theorem, ${b_1}^{10}\equiv_{11}1$.
So, $b_{30}=1$.

If $a_1=0$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

If $a_1=1$, there are $10$ cases for $b_1$. We will list $(a_0,b_0)$, $(a_1,b_1)$, $\cdots$, $(a_{30}, b_{30})$ for each case.

- $b_1=1$
  $(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1), (8, 1), (2, 1), (10, 1), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1), (8, 1), (2, 1), (10, 1), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1), (8, 1), (2, 1), (10, 1), (1, 1), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=2$
  $(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 6), (7, 3), (10, 7), (4, 10), (5, 4), (10, 7), (1, 6), (6, 9), (4, 10), (9, 2), (6, 9), (10, 7), (8, 8), (0, 1), (8, 8), (8, 8), (6, 9), (1, 6), (4, 10), (3, 5), (1, 6), (8, 8), (5, 4), (4, 10), (10, 7), (5, 4), (1, 6), (9, 2), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=3$
  $(0, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (5, 5), (10, 9), (0, 1), (10, 9), (10, 9), (1, 4), (8, 3), (0, 1), (8, 3), (8, 3), (10, 9), (5, 5), (0, 1), (5, 5), (5, 5), (8, 3), (1, 4), (0, 1), (1, 4), (1, 4), (5, 5), (10, 9), (0, 1), (10, 9), (10, 9), (1, 4), (8, 3), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=4$
  $(0, 1), (1, 4), (1, 3), (4, 9), (2, 5), (0, 1), (2, 5), (2, 5), (1, 3), (7, 4), (0, 1), (7, 4), (7, 4), (2, 5), (4, 9), (0, 1), (4, 9), (4, 9), (7, 4), (1, 3), (0, 1), (1, 3), (1, 3), (4, 9), (2, 5), (0, 1), (2, 5), (2, 5), (1, 3), (7, 4), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=5$
  $(0, 1), (1, 5), (1, 9), (10, 4), (3, 3), (0, 1), (3, 3), (3, 3), (1, 9), (6, 5), (0, 1), (6, 5), (6, 5), (3, 3), (10, 4), (0, 1), (10, 4), (10, 4), (6, 5), (1, 9), (0, 1), (1, 9), (1, 9), (10, 4), (3, 3), (0, 1), (3, 3), (3, 3), (1, 9), (6, 5), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=6$
  $(0, 1), (1, 6), (1, 2), (3, 4), (7, 8), (9, 10), (2, 3), (7, 8), (1, 2), (4, 5), (9, 10), (5, 6), (4, 5), (7, 8), (6, 7), (0, 1), (6, 7), (6, 7), (4, 5), (1, 2), (9, 10), (8, 9), (1, 2), (6, 7), (2, 3), (9, 10), (7, 8), (2, 3), (1, 2), (5, 6), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=7$
  $(0, 1), (1, 7), (1, 8), (9, 9), (7, 6), (6, 10), (10, 5), (7, 6), (1, 8), (2, 4), (6, 10), (4, 7), (2, 4), (7, 6), (8, 2), (0, 1), (8, 2), (8, 2), (2, 4), (1, 8), (6, 10), (5, 3), (1, 8), (8, 2), (10, 5), (6, 10), (7, 6), (10, 5), (1, 8), (4, 7), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=8$
  $(0, 1), (1, 8), (1, 7), (8, 5), (2, 2), (7, 10), (5, 9), (2, 2), (1, 7), (4, 3), (7, 10), (3, 8), (4, 3), (2, 2), (10, 6), (0, 1), (10, 6), (10, 6), (4, 3), (1, 7), (7, 10), (6, 4), (1, 7), (10, 6), (5, 9), (7, 10), (2, 2), (5, 9), (1, 7), (3, 8), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=9$
  $(0, 1), (1, 9), (1, 5), (6, 3), (9, 4), (0, 1), (9, 4), (9, 4), (1, 5), (2, 9), (0, 1), (2, 9), (2, 9), (9, 4), (6, 3), (0, 1), (6, 3), (6, 3), (2, 9), (1, 5), (0, 1), (1, 5), (1, 5), (6, 3), (9, 4), (0, 1), (9, 4), (9, 4), (1, 5), (2, 9), (0, 1)$
- $b_1=10$
  $(0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1), (1, 10), (1, 10), (0, 1)$

Checking the last term of all lists above, we can verify that $a_{30}=0$ for all $1\le b\le10$.

If $a_1\not=0,1$, we can let $c_i=a_i*(a_1^{-1})\% 11$ for all $i$, where $a_1^{-1}$ is the modulo 11 inverse of $a_1$. Then $c_0=1$, $c_1=1$, $c_{n+1}=(c_n+c_{n-1}b_n^9)\%11$. So we know that $c_{30}=0$. Hence $a_{30}\equiv_{11} c_{30}*a_1\equiv 0$. So $a_{30}=0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a way that avoids the manual computation of the $10$ long lists of pairs yet.

Comment: Thanks. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979935/prove-that-int1-0fxdx-le-2-int1-0-fxdx-int1-0fxdx), does the solution assume $f''$ is continuous in the first line? It looks like Fubini's theorem is used. If so, would the statement still hold if $f''$ was just integrable?